# How to stop Fiddler 2 from logging requests made from web browsers and other applications?

Tags: fiddler

I would like to use Fiddler 2 to make GET and POST requests and to analyze the responses, but it's made almost impossible because of how many other requests it logs from internet browsers and other applications.

How can I get Fiddler to only show requests that I made inside of it, along with the responses to those requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to filter traffic by process in Fiddler; a simple search on any major search engine will turn up all of them.

For your needs, however, you simply don't want Fiddler to be the system proxy. Hit F12 or untick File > Capture Traffic; no other client will then send its traffic to Fiddler.

If you only ever care about requests from the Composer, click Tools > Fiddler Options and untick "Act as System Proxy on Startup" on the Connections tab.